# how can i batch delete column comments in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I know i can delete column comment by 
`alter table tal_name modify column Field Type comment ''`.
But if i have a lot of comment to delete, how can i do that by sql script?
First time I want to use `show full columns from tal_name` to get full info so i can use cursor to delete comment, but i find i can't use the result of `show` statement just like i use `select` statement.
I also can't `create view` from the `show` result.
Maybe my thought is wrong, so is there any way to batch delete comment?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why? Where is the benefit?

Comment: You could do it in a stored proc, using info schema, a cursor, and a `prepare` with a concat string and an execute

Comment: The benefit is that when one moves scripts between server/phpmyadmin  versions, Some server/pma versions blow up when running scripts with comment lines. And we slave for sometime trying to remind ourselves of that.

Answer (score 0):

As I suppose you only have to do this once, you could follow these two steps:

First execute this query:

```
select concat('alter table ', '`',table_name,'` ',
       'modify column `', column_name,'` ',
        column_type,
        ifnull(concat(' character set ', character_set_name), ''),
        ifnull(concat(' collate ', collation_name), ''),
        if(is_nullable = 'no', ' not null ', ''),
        if(column_default is null, '', concat(' default ', quote(column_default))),
        ' ', extra, ';')
            as column_definition
from    information_schema.columns
where   table_schema like 'db%'
    and column_comment is not null;
```

...changing the condition on the table schema to your case. The output would be an SQL statement per row:

```
column_definition
---------------------------------------------------------
alter table `tab` modify column `id` int(11) not null auto_increment;
alter table `tab` modify column `name` varchar(100) not null;
```

Copy the SQL statements in that output and execute them. The absence of the `comment` clause will delete the comments on those columns.